# Constrain Text to Div

Tags: html, css, text

Aftret 3 days trying to get past this issue i give up.
is there an alternate to a div that i can use that will actually hold text ?
At the moment text ignores the div, ignores the height, width, top, bottom and boarder/margin and just dose what ever it wants . 
This is really frustrating as when resolution is changed my title which is set 0% from the top ends up at the bottom of the page overlapping the info text (which is somewhere else defying physics somehow) while both divs remain completely unaffected where they are suppose to be.

on the attacked picture the green box is where the black "Home" text should be and the Blue box is where the red text should be. there is also suppose to be a blue box somewhere on the but it seems to have took the day off...

[Image](http://i893.photobucket.com/albums/ac139/AceScottie1/StupidText_zps8b73b060.png)

```
#Info { background-color:#0F0; position:absolute; top:200px; left:20%; height:auto; width:60%; color:#FFF; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; z-index:110; bottom:20%; word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: Code please. I would guess you need to use **word-wrap** in your css

Comment: you should make a fiddle or bin with your problem seems easy enough

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after

`word-wrap: break-word;` on div containing the text

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z83Wv/1/

Comment: afraid that didnt work. still ignored the bounds of the div and went shooting down the page. i edited the post so you can see the CSS code. the div only contains font and text.

Comment: That's really weird, must be something else affectiong it. fiddle worked. I didn't change your css: http://jsfiddle.net/Z83Wv/4/

Comment: i have probably broken something elsewhere. but i will keep the code in and see if it starts working when i change other things.